# Flutter: How to create custom thumb for Slider widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, slider, flutter-layout

I want to make the thumb of the Slider widget like the image below, which is taken from the TextField cursor. Is it possible to shape the slider thumb like this and also make it go under the track? If so, how?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check the [flutter_xlider package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_xlider) it should be able to recreate what you want and it seems pretty easy to use.

Comment: Will give it a try!

Comment: But i think the question will still remain, on how to make a thumb look like the image.

Comment: you can change the thumb for an image of your choosing, just change the child of the right or left handler, if you want to create it yourself you can use customPainter but im not sure how to do ir that way